# CSS variables in Material ui - createMuiTheme

Tags: javascript, material-ui, css-variables

I am trying to create a material ui theme using the existing colors defined as css variables `my-pallette.scss`:

```
:root {
  --primary-color: '#FF0000';
  ...
}
```

And use this like this:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: 'var(--primary-color)',
    },
  },
});
```

This throws an error:

> Uncaught Error: Material-UI: Unsupported `var(--primary-color)` color.
> We support the following formats: #nnn, #nnnnnn, rgb(), rgba(), hsl(), hsla().

According to this Github thread: [Support CSS variables as theme option](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12827) this is unsupported at the moment.

Is there any workaround so I can use `var(--primary-color)` as a **primary** color in material ui `createMuiTheme`?

The end goal is to use material ui components in their simplest form with their **primary, scondary, etc** colors overwritten by my colors.

```
<Radio color="primary" />
```

I have tried using the colors from my pallets like this:

```
const cssVariables = {
  primaryColor: getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('var(--primary-color)'),
};
```

and use `cssVariables.primaryColor` but this doesn't work and feels very counterintuitive.

My last solution is to **duplicate** the palette as a normal object as use it as it is but this seems a nightmare for maintenance.

Answer (score 8):

The MUI team is currently working on a solution to support CSS variables. You can track the progress [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32049) and check the details [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/27651). There is also an official documentation [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-variables/).

*UPD of 21.12.2022*

CSS variables are supported now by the MUI as an *experimental* API, check documentation [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/overview/).

Answer (score 3):

The workaround posted by NearHuscarl gets the job done, but there's a flicker caused by the palette change. This can be avoided with lazy initialization in `useState`.

```
const cssVar = (name: string) =>
  getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(name).trim();

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [theme] = useState(() =>
    createTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: cssVar("--color-primary"),
          light: cssVar("--color-primary-light"),
          dark: cssVar("--color-primary-dark"),
          bg: cssVar("--color-primary-bg"),
          contrastText: cssVar("--color-primary-contrast-text"),
        },
      },
    })
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <YourApp />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The ugly workaround works, but I suspect you are calling `getComputedStyle()` in the module scope when the stylesheets may not be initialized yet.

Try putting it in the render method like this.

```js
const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(null);

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const color = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue("--your-css-color")
    .trim(); // the result have a leading whitespace.

  setTheme(
    createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: color
        }
      }
    })
  );
}, []);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI TextField Underline Override (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Setting colors from theme options may be more effectively. With this method you could define material ui colors as css variables.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'

import { indigo, amber } from '@mui/material/colors'
const themeOptions = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: indigo[500] },
    secondary: { main: amber[600] },
    background: { default: '#F3F6F9' },
  },
})
const colorKeys = ['background', 'common', 'error', 'grey', 'info', 'primary', 'secondary', 'success', 'text', 'warning']
const r = document.querySelector(':root')
const AppThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    colorKeys.forEach((color) => {
      const themeColorObj = themeOptions.palette[color]
      for (const key in themeColorObj) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(themeColorObj, key)) {
          const colorVal = themeColorObj[key]
          r.style.setProperty(`--color-${color}-${key}`, colorVal)
        }
      }
    })
  }, [])
  return <ThemeProvider theme={themeOptions}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
}
export default AppThemeProvider
```

With this way you could use css variables as sass or common css.

```
.dx-link-edit {
  color: var(--color-primary-main);}
```